# Programmatically Create an Array of User Objects and Print in Twig Template

Tags: 8, theming, users, hooks

**MYMODULE.module:**

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

    if ($variables['node']->bundle() == 'content_type') {

        $currentUserUID = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
        $recipients = $variables['node']->get('field_user_reference')->getValue();
        $userList = array();

        foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {

            if ($recipient['target_id'] != $currentUserUID) {
                $userList[] = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($recipient['target_id']);
            }

        }

        if ($variables['node']->getOwnerId() != $currentUserUID) {
            $userList[] = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($variables['node']->getOwnerId());
        }

        $variables['userList'] = $userList;

    }

}
```

**FILENAME.twig.html:**

```
{{ userList | render }}
```

---

I've also tried working with:

```
$recipients = $variables['node']->get('field_user_reference')->view('compact');
```

and tried to filter the UID in the `if` statement inside the `foreach`.

---

My goal is to gather all users referenced from **field_user_reference**, and add the owner of the node, while filtering out the `currentUser()` into a single array. I then need to render that array in a twig template file as a user display mode. In this instance, `compact`.

I am not sure if my impasse lies in twig rendering, or better preprocessing.

How do you render a preprocessed user object in a twig template file?

---

Notes:

```
$recipients = $variables['node']->get('field_user_reference')->view('compact');
```

does render out the referenced users in the compact view mode, however I cannot seem to filter out the current user with something like `$recipient->uid[0]->target_id != $currentUserUID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can render a list of entities you have to build a render array:

```
$variables['userList'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('user')
  ->viewMultiple($userList, 'compact');
```

Now Twig is able to render the entities:

```
{{ userList }}
```

You don't need |render, because Twig renders arrays automatically.